# Perform map only when not nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The following breaks if `names` is `nil`. How can I have this `map` execute only if it's not `nil`?

```
self.topics = names.split(",").map do |n|
  Topic.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
end
```

Comment: What do you want in `self.topics` if `names.nil?`? Would an empty array be okay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of other options:

Option 1 (checking for result of `split` when executing `map` on it):

```
names_list = names.try(:split, ",")
self.topics = names_list.map do |n|
    Topic.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
end if names_list
```

Option 2 (using `try`, which will prevent the error):

```
self.topics = names.try(:split, ",").try(:map) do |n|
    Topic.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
end
```

Comment: In your first solution, you'll still get the error when calling `split`.  And in your second solution, you'd need to call `try` on both `split` and `map`...

Comment: @PinnyM, There you go, caught me again :)  I guess I was more focused on the result of `split` than `names` itself as the question is on the result of split.  But as you've mentioned the problem is really the `names` which is what should probably be checked rather than result of `split` as `split` returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want `topics` to become if `names` is actually nil.  The most elegant solution would probably be to substitute an empty string where `names` is nil:

```
self.topics = (names || '').split(",").map do |n|
...
```

But that would assign an empty array to `topics`.  If that's not what you want, you can wrap this with a `nil` check like this:

```
if names
  self.topics = ...
end
```

Or like this:

```
self.topics = names.split(",").map do |n|
  ...
end if names
```

Comment: Is there a difference between doing `if names` and `if names.present?`

Comment: Yes, [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) is the inverse of `blank?` and will return false if `names` is not truthy (false or nil) _or_ if `names` is a blank String, Array, Hash or anything else that responds to `blank?` as true.  Calling `if names` will evaluate to false only if `names` is false or nil.

Answer (score 1):

`nil.to_s` is `""`, so try

```
names.to_s.split(",").map
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem is you're not checking to see if it's safe to perform the action, and then have to scramble to try to recover when it's not safe.

Instead, check to see if `names` is valid before you try to `split` it. You don't say what `self.topics` should be if `names` is nil, but I'd start with something like:

```
self.topics = if names.nil?
                # whatever self.topic should be if names == nil
              else
                names.split(",").map do |n|
                  Topic.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
                end
              end
```

Answer (score 0):

From ruby 2.3.0 onward, you can use the safe navigation operator (`&.`):

```
self.topics = names&.split(",").map do |n|
  Topic.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally in ruby 2.7 you can use

```rb
['Moscow', 'Norilsk'].map do |city|
  city if city == 'Norilsk'
end
=> [nil, "Norilsk"]

['Moscow', 'Norilsk'].filter_map do |city|
  city if city == 'Norilsk'
end
=> ["Norilsk"]
```